# Recommend a theme function to modify the 'Submitted by' line for a node?

Tags: 7, theming

I would like to theme the 'submitted' by date without editing the node.tpl.php file. In other words, in the template.php file.

I know this has been answered thousands of times before, but for the life of me I cannot find a good solution when searching.

Can someone suggest a theme function that uses `format_date()` or other means to manipulate this however I see fit? Specifically, I simply need to say *Submitted by: admin 2012/10/10* but I would like something to keep in my toolbox as this problem comes up on every single project I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the node info using [`template_preprocess_node`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7)

```
function template_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
 // your code
}
```

> The $variables array contains the following arguments:
>
> $node
>
> $view_mode
>
> $page

**This is the default value**

```
$variables['submitted'] = t('Submitted by !username on !datetime', array('!username' => 
  $variables['name'], '!datetime' => $variables['date']));
```

You can override is as you wish. Give a try.